# Using wildcard search/replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, search, regex, wildcards

Here's my problem: In a .txt file, I need to find and replace thousands of instances of syntax like this:

**(see (a053007djfgspwdf))**

or

**(see (a053007djfgspwdf) and (a54134xsedgeg))**

or

**(see (a053007djfgspwdf), (a9554xsdfgsdfg) and (a54134xsedgeg))**

There is a lot of variety between the beginning **(see (a** and the ending **))** text strings. Can this be set up in Notepad++ using regex? If so, how would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Sorry folks, I just find other answers complicated. (No disrespect intended towards the original posters.)

As this always shows up as the first search result, I'll add this in:

1. Open the search/replace dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then the replace tab)
2. Tick "Regular Expression" down the bottom
3. Use .* as the wildcard

For example, I wanted to remove all instances of abp="1314", abp="1313", abp="1312" etc (basically the numbers are all different, which is why you want a wildcard to get rid of them).

In the replace dialog:

Find in what: `abp=".*"`
Replace with:

(You're replacing anything within those quotes with nothing to get rid of it)

Source: https://www.organicweb.com.au/17226/general-technology/notepad-wildcard/

Comment: Using `CTRL+H` takes you directly to the `Replace` tab in the dialog box. Saves a click.

Answer (score 18):

Yes it can! Notepad++ has a RegEx search mode that you can select for all of your RegEx replacement needs.

The example below is a basic replace for anything between `(see (a...))` with the exception of a line break. You may need to modify the RegEx or write your own to fit your needs. [Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a great place to help you along with experimenting.

RegEx: `\(see \(a.+\)\)`

**Matched strings:**

```
(see (a053007djfgspwdf))
(see (a053007djfgspwdf) and (a54134xsedgeg))
(see (a053007djfgspwdf), (a9554xsdfgsdfg) and (a54134xsedgeg))
```

[image: Replace (see (a...)) with replacement]

Comment: Thanks! It found the instances of the first example **(see (a053007djfgspwdf))** but not the others. Still, a great start. I will play with it to see what else I can do. If you have further suggestions, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you click *Replace All* or continue clicking on *Replace* to cycle through matches similar to using *Find Next*? Does the text you're looking for only start with `(see (a` and end with `))`? If you have strings that end with a single parentheses, you can turn the last `\)` into the capture group `(\)|)` to match strings ending with `))` "or" `)`.

Comment: Tried a few replaces, then Replace All. After that, the search string found nothing. The text for all is:

**(see a** _varied text_ **))**

No strings with single parenthesis except perhaps typos.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative RegEx `(\(see \(a|\(a)([^\)]+)\)(\)|)` that will match on the strings in your question.

Comment: LOL you updated your answer while I was editing my response. I'll try the new one.

Comment: No joy. The edited example in the original response (screenshot) gets no results, and the \(see \(a|\(a)([^\)]+)\)(\)|) from the edit beneath the screenshot gets an invalid response result.

Comment: Using the RegEx provided in the answer `(\(see \(a|\(a)([^\)]+)\)(\)|)` I'm able to match the strings using your question's criteria. Do your strings differ from *(see (a...))*, *(see (a...)*, *(a...))* and *(a...)*?

Comment: Hmmm. With the string in your above comment, it finds PART of the text strings. For example, it finds the portion highlighted:

**(see (a98798lkjlkj)** and (a09709sdgsdg))

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `\(see \(a(.*)\)` and make sure you have ". matches newline" unchecked and "wrap around" checked.

Answer (score 1):

As some of these were too in depth for me to understand, let me show you what I did after reading all of these solutions and more to finally get a better understanding.  (this is a simple approach, might not be the best)

I wanted to remove all of my **figure** elements on the whole web page. 
*Figure 2.1,Figure 1.1,ect.*

It was:

```
<p class="td1-content b8"><span class="stepNumber">2.  </span>Select Memo from the toolbar<br><b>Figure 2.1</b></p>
```

I wanted it to end up:

```
 <p class="td1-content b8"><span class="stepNumber">2.  </span>Select Memo from the toolbar</p>
```

But each

had a different Figure number, so I used this in sublime text 2.

1. ctrl H
2. click the ".*" symbol on the bottom right of Sublime text 2, (regex)
3. typed `<br><b>Figure.*</b>`
4. replace with: -left blank

This replaced all of my instances with figures in it. notice I used .* where the numbers would of been.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The exact **regex** you'd need is:

```
\(see \(\w+\)((, \(\w+\))*( and \(\w+\)))?\)
```

For example:

[image]

On selecting *Find All in Current Document*, the result would be:

[image]

You can simply use *Replace* as per your necessity instead.

If you want to include the `a` as well in the regex, you can use:

```
\(see \(a\w+\)((, \(a\w+\))*( and \(a\w+\)))?\)
```